# Airflow tasks scheduling unique sub-tasks

Tags: airflow

Fairly new to Airflow, curious if anyone has a suggestion on how to tackle my current task.

I basically need a two-part task. I've written Python to do all of this, just not sure how to correctly Airflow-ify it.

Part 1, scans a calendar for scheduled changes.
--> If a change is found for that day, schedule a task for that day/time (part 2)

Part 2, schedules a task to put change in progress, creates some alert-suppression, perform the change task, verifies output, and marks the change as completed.

I don't quite understand how to have part 1 create tasks for part 2, and not create duplicate tasks each time the calendar scan completes.